# Getting Download URL from Firebase storage in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get download URL after uploading my file to firebase storage so far i'm able to upload the file but for the URL i keep getting undefined here is my code :

```js
onFileChanged(event) {

  const file: File = event.target.files[0];
  const metaData = { 'contentType': file.type };
  const storRef: firebase.storage.Reference = firebase.storage().ref('/MyFolder/' + file.name);
  const uploadTask: firebase.storage.UploadTask = storRef.put(file, metaData);
  console.log('Uploading:' + file.name);

  uploadTask.then((uploadSnapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) => {
    const imageUrl = uploadSnapshot.downloadURL;
    console.log('URL:' + imageUrl);
  });
}
```

any suggestions 
Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did it by replacing

```
    uploadTask.then((uploadSnapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) => {
 const imageUrl = uploadSnapshot.downloadURL;
 console.log('URL:' + imageUrl);
});
```

to

```
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
  const imageUrl = downloadURL;
  console.log('URL:' + imageUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[UploadTaskSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) no longer has a downloadURL property (click through to the API docs to see for yourself).  It was eliminated not long ago.

Instead, you should use [Reference.getDownloadURL()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL) on a Reference object to request a URL.

Answer (score 0):

The download URL is given using "snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()".

```js
  encodeImageUri(imageUri, callback) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
      var aux:any = this;
      c.width = aux.width;
      c.height = aux.height;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
      callback(dataURL);
    };
    img.src = imageUri;
  };


  uploadProfileImage(imageURI, path) {
    console.log("path = " + path);
    console.log("imageURI = " + imageURI);
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      let imageRef = storageRef.child('profile').child(path);
      this.encodeImageUri(imageURI, function (image64) {
        imageRef.putString(image64, 'data_url')
          .then(snapshot => {
            console.log("snapshot = " + snapshot);
            resolve(snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL())
          }, err => {
            reject(err);
            console.log(err);
          })
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, `UploadTaskSnapshot` no longer has a `downloadURL` property. Instead you need to use method `getDownloadURL` from `AngularFireStorageReference`.

Below is the example for start upload code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-file-upload',
    templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.scss'],
})
export class FileUploadComponent {
    task: AngularFireUploadTask;
    taskRef: AngularFireStorageReference;
    percentage: Observable<number>;
    snapshot: Observable<any>;
    downloadURL: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) {}

    startUpload(event: FileList) {
        const file = event.item(0);

        if (file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image') {
            console.error('unsupported file type');
            return;
        }

        const path = `test/${new Date().getTime()}_${file.name}`;
        const customMetadata = { app: 'My App' };

        this.taskRef = this.storage.ref(path);
        this.task = this.taskRef.put(file, { customMetadata });

        this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();
        this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges();

        this.downloadURL = this.taskRef.getDownloadURL();
    }
}
```